# How can i share the same scenario outline example across the feature and scenarios

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

Objective:-
I want the data to be used across the steps in feature file. Its not in one step, Basically i want to run the scenario with all the data in example.

```
Scenario Outline:
     Given my table for app1
     Examples:
           |data|
           |123 |
           |567 |

Scenario Outline:
      Given my table for app2
      Examples:
            |data|
            |123 |
            |567 |
```

I don't want to copy the same Examples across the scenarios and features as it will require more rework if any data changes and plus it is not a good practice. How can I achieve this in spec flow

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
It's not possible to share example tables across multiple features.

Explanation:
The main objective of using feature files is readability. Scenarios have to be clear for all team members and should serve the documentation role. One table defined in one place and referenced in multiple feature files decrease scenario readabilities. You have to remember that defining scenarios != writing code and the rule 'DRY' should not be applied here.

If you're stubborn and just have to do that you can do the following:

- save the data in e.g. excel file
- implement a 'BeforeTestRun' hook that loads the data into TestThreadContext
- use data stored in TestThreadContext in your scenarios

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we should be make a function in Script folder to defineding or preparing data instead we make steps by steps to create data, it's manually and I don't like that. Example:

```cs
public class SpecFlowForFeatureSteps {
   [Given(@"I create table by name (\.*)")]  
   public void ICreateTableByName(string tableName) {
      // TODO something in there with table name
      ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As we know Scenario Outline Example take single row and execute making separate data for each. Can background do the same here ??

Comment: Yes, the background prepares your data before run the steps. You can do anything you think.

Comment: No i don't think it will solve the problem as i want the data to be used across the steps in feature file. Its not in one step, Basically i want to run the scenario with all the data in example. how will i interpret in background as it will take datatable not a single row being used for the scenario as we get the advantage in scenario example
----------------------
Scenario Example approach
              run1 - data [row1]
              run2 - data [row2]
Background approach
             all the data will be available with me at once it wont take row it will be data 
             table

Comment: Let me clear your question.
1. Do you want to prepare the data to use across the Senarios?
2. Your data need to prepare is the data for single row in table and row is different name?

Comment: Data I have added in the scenario example [It will remain same across the scenario's]
I don't want to copy paste the same data [Scenario Outline Example]  in all the scenario 's. I want to run all the data in new iteration like [Pick a row data and execute and follow the same for remaining data/row]

Comment: Because the Scenarios dependents by <app_number> - "Given my table for app2" to define which row should use in this Scenario. I think my code is make sense in this case. Otherwise, I have no idea. Thanks.